# Excel VBA: Copying Pictures from image controls to activeX objects

Tags: excel, vba, image, activex

I have a series of images that I need to display multiple times on both forms (via image controls) and on worksheets (via activeX image controls).  I know that I could keep the files externally and use the `loadpicture` method; but there is something I want to avoid if possible.

I also know I could save and load- but again I would rather not use an external file write to perform the task. Ideally, everything will stay embedded and hidden within the file itself.

I think there maybe a solution in using the clipboard- but I couldn't get the syntax to work. The object is embedded always in the same location(s); it never moves or changes size or other properties (beyond .visible). So what I would really like to do is something simple like;

```
Sheet1.oleobjects("toImage").object.picture = frm1.fromImage.picture
```

**Edit: **
I think I've found a solution to this; but still have a related question.

I worked out that I could do what I want if I embed a series of activeX images on a sheet; then reference them in the actual controls / objects I want.  So;

```
Sheet1.oleobjects("toImage").object.picture=Sheet1.oleobjects("FromImage").object.picture
```

or

```
frm1.Controls("toImage").picture = Sheet1.oleobjects("FromImage").object.picture
```

But, the below doesn't work when I try to do the same using an inserted picture (a shape object);

```
frm1.toImage.picture =  sheet1.shape("FromImage").picture
```

..isn't valid syntax. It seems the only thing I can do with them is copy them- I couldn't use them to set the picture of another object without using the clipboard.

The solution above works for me (using a series of activeX image objects rather than pictures)- but I am curious why I can't do with using a standard picture (shape).

Comment: do you want to load an image which is embedded in a sheet into the form, or vice versa? How does the image come into the form ... from file system?

Comment: MikeD; both (sheet-to-form and form-to-sheet)- though this could be sheet-to-sheet).  All pictures will be embedded from file system.  I have updated the question with some more info- managed to find a workaround that works in this instance.  I think my question now is more aimed at why I cant do things with a picture (shape) object that I can do with a control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a picture to your Excel sheet use something like this:
(You can change `ActiveSheet` to your favorite sheet)

```
Dim aSheet As Worksheet
Dim aShape As Shape
Set aSheet = ActiveSheet
Set aShape = aSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("<FileName>", msoFalse, msoTrue, 120, 120, 200, 200)
```

And for more details :

> **Function AddPicture**(Filename As String, LinkToFile As MsoTriState, SaveWithDocument As MsoTriState, Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, Height As Single) As Shape
>
> **Function AddPicture2**(Filename As String, LinkToFile As MsoTriState, SaveWithDocument As MsoTriState, Left As Single, Top As Single, Width As Single, Height As Single, Compress As MsoPictureCompress) As Shape

---

And if you want to load a picture to your `Image` component on your form :
(Add an `Image` component to your form [: Image1])

```
Set Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("<FileName>")
```